# How to create a single elimination tournament bracket?

Tags: graphs

I would like to create a single elimination bracket that could be used for a tournament.

I am imagining something [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(tournament)#/media/File:SixteenPlayerSingleEliminationTournamentBracket.svg):

[image]

Ideally, it'd be configurable as the number of participants may vary tournament to tournament.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the skeleton, it is easy. Otherwise use `forest`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/tournament/.style={code={
   \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tournament/##1}}    
   \tikzset{tournament/.cd,#1}  
   \foreach \XX [remember=\XX as \LastXX] in {\pv{n},...,0}
   {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mym}{pow(2,\XX)}
   \ifnum\XX=\pv{n}
    \foreach \YY in {1,...,\mym}
     {\draw (-\XX*\pv{d},{(\YY-\mym/2-1/2)*\pv{l}}) 
     -- ++ (\pv{d},0) |- coordinate[pos=0.25] (p-\XX-\YY)
     (-\XX*\pv{d},{(\YY-\mym/2-1)*\pv{l}})
     ;}
   \else
    \foreach \YY [evaluate=\YY as \ZZ using {int(2*\YY)}] in {1,...,\mym}
     {
     \draw (p-\LastXX-\ZZ) -- ++ (\pv{d},0)
     |- coordinate[pos=0.25] (p-\XX-\YY) 
     (p-\LastXX-\the\numexpr\ZZ-1);
     }
   \fi}
   \draw (p-0-1) -- ++ (\pv{d},0);
}},tournament/.cd,n/.initial=2,l/.initial=1,d/.initial=2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic{tournament};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic{tournament={n=3,d=1.5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]